# Textbook Suggestions for Teaching Senior Level Geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry, education, noneuclidean-geometry

I will be teaching a senior-level class on geometry next semester. The class consists of both Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry with an axiomatic approach. Right now, it appears I have the liberty of choosing the textbook for my course.

Please let me know if you have any recommendations for a senior-level (400/4000-level) Euclidean and non-Euclidean textbook I can use to teach this class next semester. Thank you!

Comment: A site search for [`non-euclidean book`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=non-euclidean+book) has some responses you may find helpful.

Comment: I mostly used Martin in preparing http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf .  I see that I did not include Hartshorne...  Marvin Greenberg put me in his fourth edition.

Comment: I don't see the Field of Ends construction in Martin. It turns out that doing the field of ends, using diagrams consistent with an upper half plane model, leads to a very attractive placement of the field as simply the horizontal axis, similar to the real axis...

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions!